# UIImageView+AFNetworking get UIImage for URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nscache

I am using `UIImageView+AFNetworking` and am wondering if there is a way to get the `UIImage` from the cache? It seems like there should be a method to return the `UIImage` based on the URL.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking already caches images automatically ([and doesn't expose the cache publicly](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/234)).  You should just be able to request from a URL and it'll either come from the cache or it will get cached when it's downloaded from the remote website.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't `AFImageCache` private and only implemented in the `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` file? Looks that way to me...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've done a bit more research and I've changed my answer a bit and added a link to a git issue that's pretty close to what you're asking. Why not just rely on AFNetworking to do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is great AFNetworking alternative called [APSmartStorage](https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage).
It supports downloading, memory and disk cache.